# Forecast multi variate

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, prediction

I am new to data science and I want to predict a value over time, knowing that I already have the values ​​of the past.  but this value is also dependent on 3 other factors.  how can I do ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually this is done by fitting the data with a polynomial curve. You need to make assumptions on the curve (is a simple rect fine? A more complex polynomial? Your choice, depending on the data you have). Then you can extrapolate what happens in the future.

Comment: There is one another method about which I would like to discuss for multivariate time series analysis is by using Deep Learning Methods like LSTM. Here is a link for your reference https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/09/multivariate-time-series-guide-forecasting-modeling-python-codes/